# Regular expressions instead of a LIKE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I am looking at some SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Audit WHERE Description LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]Inc 123[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

What is the benefit of doing that over this:

```
SELECT * FROM Audit WHERE Description LIKE '%Inc 123%'
```

I am going to do some reading up on regular expressions this evening as I have not used them for a while.  I have done some basic Googling over the last hour or so, however I am no closer to an answer.

It would help if I knew what benefit this regular expression was adding to the where clause.

Comment: They are different patterns.  It depends what. pattern you want to look for.

Comment: inc 123 is in a load of random text (bad design I know - it is a third party database).

Answer (score 0):

The first will not match: `'finc 1234'`.  The second will.

Whether that is important or not depends on what you want to do.

The second is definitely simpler.

Comment: What is the reg ex saying in structured English? I realize I need to read up on this more.

Comment: Is it saying - if there is a letter or number before or after inc 123 e.g. inc 1234 or pinc 123, then it is not a match?